# Age graph delete constraints

Tags: graph-databases, apache-age

Are there constraints I can add to my graph when an edge is deleted to

- Delete all vertices associated with the deleted edge relationship
- Preserve/retain the vertices associated with the deleted edge

And what happens to an edge when all the vertices involved has been deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You can define constraints by using triggers that would fire up when ever an event such as edge deletion occurs. Write a trigger function to delete/retain all vertices associated with a deleted edge.

And if all vertices are deleted then the edge in concern will also be deleted as an edge cannot exist without vertices.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache AGE if you have two vertices connected with an edge and try to delete one of the vertices you will get the following error :

`Cannot delete vertex v, because it still has edges attached. To delete this vertex, you must first delete the attached edges`

So you must delete the edges connecting the two vertices first or you can use `DETACH DELETE` to delete all the edges associated with the vertex first and then delete the vertex itself.

Also if you want to add constraints you can use triggers as [@han answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76235474/17768842) suggested to cascade/prevent the delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a trigger that activates upon the deletion of an edge and in turn deletes all vertices connected to that edge by *activating*.

Answer (score 0):

> Delete all vertices associated with the deleted edge relationship

Age does not support cascading delete meaning deleting an edge will not automatically delete all vertices that it connects to. To delete all the vertices associated with a deleted edge, you can either do it manually, do use `DETATCH DELETE` as give in the [AGE documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/delete.html#delete).

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (v:Useless)
    DETACH DELETE v
$$) as (v agtype);
```

> Preserve/retain the vertices associated with the deleted edge.

This is Apache AGE's default behaviour. When you delete an edge, its connecting vertices are not affected.

```
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('test+_graph', $$
    MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) 
    WHERE n.name = "ABC" and m.name = "XYZ"
    DELETE r
$$) as (r agtype);
```

> And what happens to an edge when all the vertices involved has been deleted?

It is not possible to delete all the vertices while an edge is still attached to them. In which case, it will return an error:

```
ERROR:  Cannot delete vertex n, because it still has edges attached. To delete this vertex, you must first delete the attached edges.
```

This is because, it is not possible for an edge to exist without its corresponding vertices.

- Therefore, to delete all the vertices attach to an edge, you first need to detach the corresponding edge.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all vertices associated with the edge relationship, you can do the following, which uses the `DETACH` option to first delete the edge and then delete the vertexes themselves.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('Demo', $$
    MATCH (n)-[:REL_TYPE]-(m)
    DETACH DELETE n, m
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

For deleting just the edge but not the associated vertices, simply use the `DELETE` clause for the specified edge.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('Demo', $$
    MATCH (n)-[r:REL_TYPE]-(m)
    DELETE r
$$) AS (v agtype);
```

As for the last question, it is required to first delete the edge first, and only then will you be able to delete the vertices, so that would not be possible.

You can read more to find out more about the clauses from the [AGE master documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/delete.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Age deleting an edge doesn't require deleting its vertices

You can delete an edge using query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n {name: 'Andres'})-[r:KNOWS]->()
    DELETE r
$$) as (v agtype);
```

To delete a vetrex connected with an edge you should delete this edge (edges) first to delete this vertex to solve this using `DETACH` clause
ex:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (v:Useless)
    DETACH DELETE v
$$) as (v agtype);
```

to know more about DELETE clause refer to the [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/delete.html#delete)